# Download startup config from Cisco device using SCP

Tags: cisco, configuration, scp, ios

I can successfully download the config from Juniper network devices using SCP - I'd like to do the same for a Cisco router.

SSH access is already working, and I've enabled SCP using `ip scp server enable`. Problem is that I don't know the name or location of the file I need to download, and GUI tools like WinSCP don't seem to work (complains that I need a BASH shell).

Is this possible for Cisco devices?

Answer (score 1):

Cisco doesn't require scp enabled to copying from itself.Enough to properly configure ssh server on remote machine.

**FreeBSD**

`vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
 --skip--
PasswordAuthentication yes## uncomment this line`

Then run from Cisco device:

```
Router#copy startup-config scp://user:pass@host/filename`
```

File will be saved in your home dir.